# Summary of multiple hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, sum

Via selection I get the following response:

```
=> [{:month=>[3, 3, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
:dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:", "28.10:", "27.10:", "26.10:", "25.10:", "24.10:", "23.10:", "22.10:", "21.10:", "20.10:", "19.10:", "18.10:", "17.10:", "16.10:", "15.10:", "14.10:", "13.10:", "12.10:", "11.10:", "10.10:", "09.10:", "08.10:", "07.10:", "06.10:", "05.10:", "04.10:", "03.10:", "02.10:", "01.10:"]},
{:month=>[1, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
:dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:", "28.10:", "27.10:", "26.10:", "25.10:", "24.10:", "23.10:", "22.10:", "21.10:", "20.10:", "19.10:", "18.10:", "17.10:", "16.10:", "15.10:", "14.10:", "13.10:", "12.10:", "11.10:", "10.10:", "09.10:", "08.10:", "07.10:", "06.10:", "05.10:", "04.10:", "03.10:", "02.10:", "01.10:"]}]
```

In this example there are two groups of hashes. There could be more results
but the dates will be the same  every time.

Is there an easy way to combine it to the following result?

```
[{:month=>[4, 6, 14, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
:dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:", "28.10:", "27.10:", "26.10:", "25.10:", "24.10:", "23.10:", "22.10:", "21.10:", "20.10:", "19.10:", "18.10:", "17.10:", "16.10:", "15.10:", "14.10:", "13.10:", "12.10:", "11.10:", "10.10:", "09.10:", "08.10:", "07.10:", "06.10:", "05.10:", "04.10:", "03.10:", "02.10:", "01.10:"]}
```

For Arrays I could use `transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(:+)}` but not for hashes.
Is there a similar solution for hashes?

Comment: notice that you have an array of hashes :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Your question is premature. You should show us your attempt, along with a question about the specific problem. You're asking us to give you the code, which results in multiple different ways of doing it, and usually none will fit your current code resulting in you having to shoehorn it in.

Comment: Thanks for the greenie, but in future please consider waiting longer before making a selection.  A quick selection may discourage other answers and short-circuit others who are still working on their answers. There's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hour before making a selection (some wait much longer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arr = [{ :month=>[3, 3, 9], :dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:"] },
       { :month=>[1, 3, 5], :dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:"] },
       { :month=>[2, 4, 6], :dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:"] }]

{ :month=>arr.map { |h| h[:month] }.transpose.map { |a| a.reduce(:+) },
  :dates=>arr.first[:dates] }
  #=> {:month=>[6, 10, 20], :dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:"]}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = arr.map { |h| h[:month] }
  #=> [[3, 3, 9], [1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]] 
b = a.transpose
  #=> [[3, 1, 2], [3, 3, 4], [9, 5, 6]] 
c = b.map { |a| a.reduce(:+) }
  #=> [6, 10, 20] 
d = arr.first
  #=> {:month=>[3, 3, 9], :dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:"]} 
e = d[:dates]
  #=> ["30.10:", "29.10:"] 
{ :month=>c, :dates=>e }
  #=> {:month=>[6, 10, 20], :dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the array of hashes in the response:

```
@hashes = [{:month=>[3, 3, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
:dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:", "28.10:", "27.10:", "26.10:", "25.10:", "24.10:", "23.10:", "22.10:", "21.10:", "20.10:", "19.10:", "18.10:", "17.10:", "16.10:", "15.10:", "14.10:", "13.10:", "12.10:", "11.10:", "10.10:", "09.10:", "08.10:", "07.10:", "06.10:", "05.10:", "04.10:", "03.10:", "02.10:", "01.10:"]},
{:month=>[1, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
:dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:", "28.10:", "27.10:", "26.10:", "25.10:", "24.10:", "23.10:", "22.10:", "21.10:", "20.10:", "19.10:", "18.10:", "17.10:", "16.10:", "15.10:", "14.10:", "13.10:", "12.10:", "11.10:", "10.10:", "09.10:", "08.10:", "07.10:", "06.10:", "05.10:", "04.10:", "03.10:", "02.10:", "01.10:"]}]
```

You can use [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to combine them both and get the result you supplied in your example:

```
result = @hashes.inject({}) do |memo, hash|
  memo[:month] ||= []
  memo[:dates] ||= []
  memo[:month] += hash[:month]
  memo[:dates] += hash[:dates]
  memo
end
```

Now result looks like your example:

```
result == {
  :month=>[3, 3, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  :dates=>["30.10:", "29.10:", "28.10:", "27.10:", "26.10:", "25.10:", "24.10:", "23.10:", "22.10:", "21.10:", "20.10:", "19.10:", "18.10:", "17.10:", "16.10:", "15.10:", "14.10:", "13.10:", "12.10:", "11.10:", "10.10:", "09.10:", "08.10:", "07.10:", "06.10:", "05.10:", "04.10:", "03.10:", "02.10:", "01.10:", "30.10:", "29.10:", "28.10:", "27.10:", "26.10:", "25.10:", "24.10:", "23.10:", "22.10:", "21.10:", "20.10:", "19.10:", "18.10:", "17.10:", "16.10:", "15.10:", "14.10:", "13.10:", "12.10:", "11.10:", "10.10:", "09.10:", "08.10:", "07.10:", "06.10:", "05.10:", "04.10:", "03.10:", "02.10:", "01.10:"]
}
```

Comment: Instead of `inject` I'd recommend using `each_with_object`. It results in a little cleaner code. Also, `memo = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }` will remove the need to pre-check and assign empty hashes further cleaning up the code.